# Scientific Horror Movie from the late 80's early 90's

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I was quite young (toddler) when I saw this so my memory's might be quite fuzzy.

It was seen in either late 80's or very early in the 90's.

The movie was about a monster/alien creature that would kidnap people, than use a sort of tentacle connected to its right arm that would strike the victims in their chest, and suck blood out of it, then collect the blood in tiny vials in an apparatus on its arm, some sort of high-tech gauntlet.

The movie might however been older, since my siblings enjoyed other movie content, but my only clue temporal wise is from when I saw it.

What's clouded to me, so take this part with a grain of salt, is that the creature was brownish, probably a bronze-ish metal suit.

A scene I clearly remember was a woman being bound, her shirt being ripped open by the creature's hands, and then the tentacle like appendage striking her in the middle of her sternum.

I'll update this question once I remember more details.

Comment: Sounds like a great movie for toddlers.

Comment: i know, gave me nightmares for a few months...but i was very stubborn to be with my siblings at all times, and back then we weren't very strict with movie ratings, Still trying to figure out which movie it is, haven't had luck on google, and my siblings can't remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The movie is called *I Come in Peace***

Starring Dolph Lundgren, from 1990.

The alien (a humanoid) is on Earth to harvest endorphins from humans, which is used by other aliens as a drug. In order to produce them, he injects the humans with heroin (through the tentacle mentioned), which causes them to produce the endorphins as they OD, and he then jams a spike into their skulls to suck the endorphins out of their brains. The vials you remember are the vials of heroin being injected, and other vials filling with the extracted chemicals. Dolph plays a human cop who is investigating the deaths.

The scene you mention in particular is a garage mechanic that is attacked and killed partway through the film when he enters her shop.

Comment: The alternative name for the movie (by which I knew it) is *Dark Angel*. I think that was how it was released in at least some major Asian markets. In fact according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Come_in_Peace), that was the original intended name but it was renamed in the US prior to release to avoid confusion with other movies named "Dark Angel".